# How to find Non repeat Occurrence of column with respect to another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'order No':[71,71,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,72,72,72,73,73],'product id':[123,12,123,123,123,15,16,14,112,15,112,112,12,112,100,101],'Category':['product','service','product','product','product','service','service','service','product','service','product','product','service','product','service','service']})
>>> df
    order No  product id Category
0         71         123  product
1         71          12  service
2         71         123  product
3         71         123  product
4         71         123  product
5         71          15  service
6         71          16  service
7         72          14  service
8         72         112  product
9         72          15  service
10        72         112  product
11        72         112  product
12        72          12  service
13        72         112  product
14        73         100  service
15        73         101  service
```

Expected output:

```
order No  Category  COunt of product
71        Product   2
72        Product   3
```

How to find count of Non repeat Cateogory =Product against each order no

---

Actually,required output is non repetitive 'order no,product id,category(only for product),here only index 0 and index 2 has to consider for order no 71.index 3 and 4 is repetitive,because there is no new combination between index 3 and 4.that is how i got 2.And similarly for order no 72,only index 8,10 and 13 has to consider to get count 3

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: A simple `groupby` with `count` should be enough. But how can you get 2 and 3 with this input data?

Comment: Actually,required output is non repetitive 'order no,product id,category(only for product),here only index 0 and index 2 has to consider for  order no 71.index 3 and 4 is repetitive,because there is no new combination between index 3 and 4.that is how  i got 2.And similarly for order no 72,only index 8,10 and 13 has to consider to get count 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to filter rows that are identical to the previous from the dataframe before extracting the number or orders for a category.

For the first part, you can just compare the dataframe with its shift, and reject lines where all columns are the same:

```
print(df.loc[(df.shift()!=df).any(axis=1)])
```

gives:

```
    order No  product id Category
0         71         123  product
1         71          12  service
2         71         123  product
5         71          15  service
6         71          16  service
7         72          14  service
8         72         112  product
9         72          15  service
10        72         112  product
12        72          12  service
13        72         112  product
14        73         100  service
15        73         101  service
```

To only considere the `product` category, just add a condition:

```
df.loc[(~(df.shift() == df).all(axis=1))&(df.Category=='product')]
```

gives:

```
    order No  product id Category
0         71         123  product
2         71         123  product
8         72         112  product
10        72         112  product
13        72         112  product
```

And finally `groupby` and `count`:

```
resul = df.loc[(~(df.shift() == df).all(axis=1))
   &(df.Category=='product')].groupby(['order No', 'Category']).count()
```

which is as expected:

```
                   product id
order No Category            
71       product            2
72       product            3
```